# How to Adjust Spacing in Blogger Mobile Template?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, mobile, blogger

I've been wracking my brain trying to figure out how to alter my Blogger mobile template to get rid of the spacing between by Adsense banner, my banner and navigation. For some reason there is a blue strip in between both of them.

This is only giving me issues in the mobile template. Here [is a link to my blog for reference](http://www.bluejayhunter.com).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your css for mobile template, you have this:

```
html .header-outer {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

html .main-outer {
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}
```

Remove the margin styles or override them to get your mobile view to look correct.

Comment: Thank you! I added some custom CSS to overwrite those margins. Looks good now, thanks!

Comment: Great! if my answer helped, would u mind accepting it as the answer?